# Extremely poor text wrapping in nested Discussions on mobile

Tags: bug, status-planned, design, flags, collectives

[image]

I flagged a Discussion, and found this:

The flag icon is tiny, the word Flagged is wrapped every two letters, and Share is wrapped partway through.

If it matters, I'm on mobile iOS.

To protect the user, I'm not linking, but when the rep is AAA.Bk, it renders with the decimal point and everything after it on a new line, which isn't ideal. I don't have a specific idea there, but maybe the author label could be condensed to OP, which would give more space for the rep value.

I'm not a UI/UX designer, but one idea would be to move Share into the three dots menu to provide more space for the Flagged text.

Can this be updated to have the wrapping look nicer?

Comment: Thanks for reporting, we have this bug logged and planned already (from internal testing) and so it should get fixed soon.

Comment: [Handling these flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFOiW.jpg) is also somewhat difficult.